# How to get access Token of active Session with simple Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

I am using library SimpleFacebook and I need to get accessToken of current session.
In standard fb sdk it looks like this:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    String accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
}
```

but how to get this string with library SimpleFacebook?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SimpleFacebook mSimpleFacebook;
mSimpleFacebook=SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this);

Session session=mSimpleFacebook.getSession();
AccessToken accessToken=session.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: there is no such method like mSimpleFacebook.getSession();

Comment: I am using old library of `Simple Facebook` library in which this method is there. In new library use `SessionManager` class to get Access Token.I have not used new library so I don't know exactly how to get it from this class.

Answer (score 0):

In the onResume() Method of your code you can use this :

```
 Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
 String token = session.getAccessToken()
```

or you can even use this(Note : This is applicable only After Facebook SDK version 4.X)

```
AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the accessToken as a String you actually need to use `String accessToken = mSimpleFacebook.getAccessToken().getToken()`

So if you change your code to the following it should work:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    String accessToken = session.getAccessToken().getToken();
}
```